# Drupal Zen subtheme - stop responsiveness at specific breakpoint

Tags: css, drupal, sass, drupal-themes, drupal-zen

Im devoloping a Drupal Zen subtheme.

When resizing the browser, the Zen correctly resizes everything to fit the browser/window size. Thats great, but is there a way to tell Zen to stop being responsive at a certain breakpoint?

Comment: There are two files in zen grid system (zen-internals/css/layouts/)
, responsive and fix. you can use one of them. If need do something fix, then you can add media query for certain break point and then change percentage width to something fix width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just apply `max-width` to container.